why blocprovider is not updating the state of the ui?
I am making an infinite scroll view in flutter with bloc state management, the issue is that my state is not updating when I go to the bottom of the screen, I noticed that when I call the ..add(FetchAllProductEvent) function in the blocprovider it is fetching me the initial products, but when i call it in the onscroll function it is not updating the ui, as I can also see the logs that the onscroll function is called properly and the API calls have been made. But my blocbuilder is not reacting to the states. also, when I call it in, initstate, the state is not even working for initial products.
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:boteek/src/blocs/category/category_bloc.dart';
import 'package:boteek/src/blocs/product/product_bloc.dart';
import 'package:boteek/src/data/product_repository.dart';
import 'package:boteek/src/models/product_model.dart';
import 'package:boteek/src/presentation/constants/color.dart';
import 'package:boteek/src/presentation/screens/product_screen.dart';
import 'package:boteek/src/presentation/widgets/buttons/k_button.dart';
import 'package:boteek/src/presentation/widgets/misc/circular_progress_indicator.dart';
import 'package:boteek/src/presentation/widgets/products/product_card.dart';
import 'package:boteek/src/presentation/widgets/shimmer/home_shimmer.dart';
import 'package:boteek/src/presentation/widgets/shimmer/product_shimmer.dart';
import 'package:boteek/src/presentation/widgets/textfields/normal_field.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String selectedCategory = "All";
  List<String> categories = ["All"];
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(_onScroll);
    
     BlocProvider.of<ProductBloc>(context).
     add(FetchAllProductEvent());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
   
  }

  void _onScroll() {
    if (_scrollController.position.pixels != 0 && _scrollController.position.atEdge) {
      BlocProvider.of<ProductBloc>(context).add(FetchAllProductEvent());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => CategoryBloc(productRepository: ProductRepository())
              ..add(FetchAllCategoriesEvent()),
          ),
          BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => ProductBloc()
             // ..add(FetchAllProductEvent()),
          ),
        ],
        child: Column(
          children: [
            BlocConsumer<CategoryBloc, CategoryState>(
              listener: (context, state) {
                if (state is AllCategoriesSuccessState) {
                  setState(() {
                    categories.addAll(state.categories.map((category) => category.categoryName));
                  });
                }
              },
              builder: (context, state) {
                return const SizedBox();
              },
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: BlocBuilder<ProductBloc, ProductState>(
                builder: (context, state) {
                  log("the state is $state");
                  if (state is AllProductFailureState) {
                    return Center(child: Text(state.error));
                  }
                  if (state is AllProductLoadingState && state.isFirstFetch) {
                    return _buildLoading();
                  }

                  List<Product> _product = [];
                  bool isLoading = false;
                  if (state is AllProductLoadingState) {
                    _product = state.oldProducts;
                    isLoading = true;
                  } else if (state is AllProductSuccessState) {
                    _product = state.products;
                  }

                  final filteredProducts = selectedCategory == "All"
                      ? _product
                      : _product.where((product) => product.categories.contains(selectedCategory)).toList();

                  return CustomScrollView(
                    controller: _scrollController,
                    slivers: [
                      SliverList(
                        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                          banner(size: size),
                          const SizedBox(height: 10),
                          searchBar(size: size),
                          const SizedBox(height: 10),
                          categoryTab(size: size),
                          const SizedBox(height: 10),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: size.height * 0.05,
                            child: ListView.builder(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              itemCount: categories.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      selectedCategory = categories[index];
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: size.width * 0.04,
                                        vertical: size.height * 0.01),
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: size.width * 0.01),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: selectedCategory == categories[index]
                                            ? Colors.white
                                            : Colors.black,
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                        border: selectedCategory != categories[index]
                                            ? Border.all(color: Colors.white)
                                            : null),
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: Text(
                                        categories[index],
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: selectedCategory == categories[index]
                                              ? Colors.black
                                              : Colors.white,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 10),
                        ]),
                      ),
                      
                      SliverGrid(
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: (size.width < 600) ? 2 : 4,
                          crossAxisSpacing: size.width * 0.02,
                          mainAxisSpacing: size.height * 0.02,
                          childAspectRatio: (size.width < 600) ? 0.55 : 0.75,
                        ),
                        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                          (context, index) {
                            if (index < filteredProducts.length) {
                              final product = filteredProducts[index];
                              return GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, ProductScreen.routeName,
                                      arguments: {'productId': product.productId});
                                },
                                child: KProductCard(
                                  imageUrl: product.productUrl,
                                  discount: product.discount,
                                  price: product.amount,
                                  isLiked: true,
                                  productTitle: "$index ${product.productName}",
                                ),
                              );
                            } else {
                              Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 30), () {
                                _scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
                              });
                              return const SizedBox(
                                height: 100,
                                child: Center(child: CircularLoader()),
                              );
                            }
                          },
                          childCount: filteredProducts.length + (isLoading ? 1 : 0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildLoading() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          HomeShimmer(),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
            child: GridView.builder(
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 7.0,
                mainAxisSpacing: 0.0,
                childAspectRatio: 0.59,
              ),
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ProductShimmer();
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class categoryTab extends StatelessWidget {
  const categoryTab({
    super.key,
    required this.size,
  });

  final Size size;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: size.width * 0.02),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Text("Categories"),
          InkWell(
            child: Text(
              "View All",
              style: TextStyle(color: AppColour.grey),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class searchBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const searchBar({
    super.key,
    required this.size,
  });

  final Size size;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: size.width * 0.02),
      child: KTextField(
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
        hintText: "What product you're looking for?",
        suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.filter_alt_outlined),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class banner extends StatelessWidget {
  const banner({
    super.key,
    required this.size,
  });

  final Size size;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Container(
      height: size.height * 0.2,
      width: size.width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: AppColour.categoryButtonDark,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
      ),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            left: -50,
            child: Transform.rotate(
              angle: 180 * 3.1415927 / 180,
              child: Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 200,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage(
                        "assets/images/ring_bottom_right.png"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: -10,
            right: -32,
            child: Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 200,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(
                      "assets/images/ring_bottom_right.png"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          // Text and button
          Positioned(
            left: 20,
            top: 30,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  "Discover Products",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 30,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                KButton(
                  width: size.width * 0.3,
                  height: size.height * 0.021,
                  buttonText: "Shop Now",
                  onPressed: () {},
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

product_bloc.dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:boteek/src/data/product_repository.dart';
import 'package:boteek/src/models/category_model.dart';
import 'package:boteek/src/models/product_description_model.dart';
import 'package:boteek/src/models/product_model.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

part 'product_event.dart';
part 'product_state.dart';

class ProductBloc extends Bloc<ProductEvent, ProductState> {
  int page = 1;
  ProductRepository productRepository = ProductRepository();
  ProductBloc() : super(ProductInitial()) {
    on<FetchNewInProductsEvent>(_fetchNewInProduct);
    on<FetchAllProductEvent>(_fetchAllProduct);
    on<FetchAllCategoryEvent>(_fetchAllCategories);
    on<FetchTheProductEvent>(_fetchTheProduct);
   // on<FetchMoreProductEvent>(_onFetchMoreProducts);
  }

   FutureOr<void> _fetchAllProduct(FetchAllProductEvent event, Emitter<ProductState> emit) async {
      
      try{
      if(state is AllProductLoadingState) return;
      final currentState = state;
      var oldProducts = <Product>[];
      if(currentState is AllProductSuccessState){
        oldProducts = currentState.products;
      }
      emit(AllProductLoadingState(oldProducts,isFirstFetch: page == 1));
      var newProducts = await productRepository.getAllProduct(page);
        
        print("new products $newProducts");
        page = page + 1;
        final products = (state as AllProductLoadingState).oldProducts;
        products.addAll(newProducts);
        print("new product size ${products.length}");
        emit(AllProductSuccessState(products));
    
      } catch(e){
        emit(AllProductFailureState(e.toString()));
      } 
  }
 
  Future<void> _fetchNewInProduct(event, emit) async {
    if (event is FetchNewInProductsEvent) {
      emit(NewInProductLoadingState());
      try {
        List<Product> products = await productRepository.getNewInProduct();

        emit(NewInProductSuccessState(products));
      } catch (e) {
        print(e.toString());
        emit(NewInProductFailureState(e.toString()));
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> _fetchAllCategories(event, emit) async {
    if (event is FetchAllCategoryEvent) {
      emit(AllCategoriesLoadingState());
      try {
        List<Category> categories = await productRepository.getAllCategories();
        emit(AllCategoriesFetchedState(categories));
      } catch (e) {
        emit(AllCategoriesFailedState(e.toString()));
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> _fetchTheProduct(event, emit) async {
    if (event is FetchTheProductEvent) {
      int productId = event.productId;
      emit(ProductDetailsLoadingState());
      try {
        ProductDescription product =
            await productRepository.getProduct(event.productId);
        emit(ProductDetailsFetchedState(product));
      } catch (e) {
        emit(ProductDetailsFailedState(e.toString()));
      }
    }
  }

 
}

product_state.dart
part of 'product_bloc.dart';

@immutable
sealed class ProductState {}

final class ProductInitial extends ProductState {}

class AllProductLoadingState extends ProductState {
  final List<Product> oldProducts;
  final bool isFirstFetch;
  AllProductLoadingState(this.oldProducts,{this.isFirstFetch=false});
}

class AllProductSuccessState extends ProductState {
  final List<Product> products;
  AllProductSuccessState(this.products);
}

class AllProductFailureState extends ProductState {
  final String error;
  AllProductFailureState(this.error);
}

class NewInProductLoadingState extends ProductState {}

class NewInProductSuccessState extends ProductState {
  final List<Product> products;

  NewInProductSuccessState(this.products);
}

class NewInProductFailureState extends ProductState {
  final String error;

  NewInProductFailureState(this.error);
}

class AllCategoriesFetchedState extends ProductState {
  final List<Category> categories;
  AllCategoriesFetchedState(this.categories);
}

class AllCategoriesLoadingState extends ProductState {}

class AllCategoriesFailedState extends ProductState {
  final String error;
  AllCategoriesFailedState(this.error);
}

class ProductDetailsFetchedState extends ProductState {
  final ProductDescription product;
  ProductDetailsFetchedState(this.product);
}

class ProductDetailsLoadingState extends ProductState {}

class ProductDetailsFailedState extends ProductState {
  final String error;
  ProductDetailsFailedState(this.error);
}

class MoreProductLoadingState extends ProductState {}

class MoreProductSuccessState extends ProductState {
  final List<Product> products;

  MoreProductSuccessState({required this.products});
}


Can you try using equatable package? These happens many times like you are updating the state but props are not change and the same state has been pushed before so the UI does not update
